# What's Wrong With My Javascript Code? It Won't Run

Tags: javascript, html

```
var malediv = document.querySelector('.male');
        var femalediv = document.querySelector('.female');
        var male_sources = [
          "/images/m1.png",
          "/images/m2.png",
          "/images/m3.png",
          "/images/m4.png",
          "/images/m5.png",
          "/images/m6.png",
          "/images/m7.png",
          "/images/m8.png",
        ]
        var female_sources = [
          "/images/f1.png",
          "/images/f2.png",
          "/images/f3.png",
          "/images/f4.png",
          "/images/f5.png",
          "/images/f6.png",
          "/images/f7.png",
          "/images/f8.png",
        ]


        function displayRandMaleImage() {
          malediv.innerHTML = "";
          var malerandom_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 
male_sources.length);
          var random_male_image_source = male_sources[malerandom_number];
         maleimg = document.createElement('img');
          maleimg.setAttribute('src', random_male_image_source);
          malediv.append(maleimg);
          alert('maleimagedisplayed');
        }
    function displayRandFemaleImage() {
      femalediv.innerHTML = "";
      var femrandom_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * female_sources.length);
      var random_female_image_source = female_sources[femrandom_number];
      femaleimg = document.createElement('img');
      femaleimg.setAttribute('src', random_female_image_source);
      div.append(femaleimg);
    }
    function displayRandImages(){
      displayRandMaleImage();
      displayRandFemaleImage();
      alert('SKEEET');
    }
```

none of my display random image fundtions are working in my html page that this is embedded in. I even added a test function "anAlert" that works perfectly. Please help me to understand what i can do to make this work.

Comment: See any errors in console? Post your HTML too so the problem is reproducible?

Comment: There should be at least _one_ error in the console because there is no function with name `displayRandomImage`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons why it isn't working.

1) You haven't defined the button. Which should've been done like:

```
var button = document.querySelector('.button_class');
```

or using the id:

```
var button = document.getElementById('button_id');
```

2) Your function to call the other two display functions is named `displayRandImages()`

```
function displayRandImages(){
    displayRandMaleImage();
    displayRandFemaleImage();
    alert('SKEEET');
}
```

whereas, you've used the function `displayRandomImage()` in your click event:

`button.addEventListener('click', displayRandomImage);`

```
displayRandImages() != displayRandomImage()
```

Comment: sorry the button was obsolete code. the functions are called on the page loading in <body onload=""> and no functions work if I call anything other than anAlert()

Answer (score 0):

button is not defined

```
button.addEventListener('click', displayRandomImage);
```

You should use it like

```
document.getElementById('buttonid').addEventListener('click', displayRandImages);
```

where 'buttonid' is id of your button, should be defined in html.
One more thing, as you are accessing button outside any other js function, So it'll be called on page load.
So you have to write this javascript after your html code so that it'll be called after button element rendered in HTML.